# Use less than 5 anchor scales in FPN object detection model

Tags: computer-vision, object-detection

Usually the anchors sizes are set to {32, 64, 128, 256, 512}. However, in my dataset, I don't have boxes as large as 512 x 512. So I would like to use only 4 anchor scales i.e. {32, 64, 128, 256}. How would this be possible, since the FPN has 5 levels?

To elaborate, consider the following image. (It's from an [article](https://medium.com/@hirotoschwert/digging-into-detectron-2-47b2e794fabd) about detectron2)

[image: Generalised RCNN with FPN]

Decreasing the number of anchors isn't really straightforward since removing a scale involves removing a stage of the resnet (resnet block) from being used. Both the BoxHead and the RPN expects P2 to P5 (RPN expects res5/P6 as well). So my question is if I were to remove an anchor scale (in my case 512 x 512, since my images are only 300 x 300 and objects won't exceed that size) which resnet block should be ignored. Should the low resolution block (res2) be ignored or should the high res (res5) be removed?

Or is it that the structure does not allow removal of an anchor scale and 5 scales must be used?

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the anchor scale, but be aware to also modify your RPN and your BoxHead. The P2 will have the largest dimension (512 in your case).

But maybe think about keeping all of them and changing only the resolutions, beginning from 16 to 256. I guess this can save you from a lot of reorganization of your model plus will improve detection for smaller objects.